# I have load xml from remote machine

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have url like

```
http://steepgraph5-pc/sgs/Client/Innovator.xml
```

from that url I load Innovator.xml into XmlDocument and get node that contain path like

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Aras\\Innovator\\InnovatorServerConfig.xml
```

now I have to load InnovatorServerConfig.xml into new XmlDocumnet but this path is local to server and i have to load it from client. I am using c#

C# code is like:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("http://steepgraph5-pc/sgs/Client/Innovator.xml");
string path=document.SelectSingleNode("/ConfigFilePath/@value").Value;
XmlDocument ServerConfigdocument = new XmlDocument();
ServerConfigdocument.Load(path);
```

Comment: Do you have access/permissions to access the Server from client?

Comment: yes i have access to server

Comment: Then what is the problem you are having, i dont understand.

Comment: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Aras\\Innovator\\InnovatorServerConfig.xml is a path local to server machine  but not local to my machine. please give me code

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to convert an arbitrary file system path to a means to access that path from a remote computer.

You need to have some sort of network protocol to access it. You appear to have selected HTTP.

Given that you are using HTTP, you have to:

- Be wanting to access a file that the server actually makes available
- Know how the server maps its Document Root onto the file system

Then you can convert the file path to a URL.

This isn't a sensible thing to do on the client. It would make more sense for the server to rewrite the XML and replace the local path with an HTTP URI.

Comment: thanks for reply but i need code to convert path to URL and load XML into XmlDocument

Comment: @AmitNawale — You have the code to load an HTTP URL into an XmlDocument already. We can't write the code to convert the path to the URL because we don't know if the first bullet point is true and we don't know the information required by the second bullet point. (Because both depend on how your server is configured).

Answer (score 0):

Innovator server config is just a file loaded by the Innovator server side when it starts up.

If you edit it it will have no effect until you restart the IIS webserver.

I'd recommend just remote desktop to the server, edit the file and restart the webserver.

If you wish to to this remotely, then you can make the Innovator root folder accessible via WEBDAV.  This can be mounted or browsed by any remote machine as though it is a local disk.
Then after editing, use the remote management capability of IIS to restart the server.